Cannot find class dependencies using jdeps for JDK 16, 17, 21
I have created a Java module and packaged it in test.jar. It contains test.Main.class. I am able to run this module using the command:
java --module-path test.jar --module test/test.Main

I am also able to run jdeps on the test.jar:
jdeps --module-path test.jar

However, when I run:
jdeps -cp test.jar test.Main

I get this message and no other output:
"Warning: Path does not exist: test.Main"

Also, I tried the same command with jdeps from my Java 8 installation and it works fine. But it does not work with JDK 16, 17, and 21. Any idea why?
Basically, I am just trying to find out the dependencies of test.Main class. Can't I do that with the current jdeps?

Dot you mean java -cp test.jar test.Main rather than jdeps -cp test.jar test.Main, or just jdeps test.jar?

@DuncG No, I mean jdeps!
I want to find out the dependencies of test.Main class, which is packaged in test.jar

I'm not sure about test.Main specifically but this should show the dependencies of the test package of self contained jar:  jdeps -p test test.jar or just jdeps test.jar for the entire jar's dependencies
